# ¿Como validar un objeto en NestJS?

Tags: typescript, mongodb, validación, nestjs

Buen día.
Estoy intentando validar con class-validator en NestJs.
Ya logre validar String como quería, pero mi duda surge a la hora de validar el contenido de un objeto.
En express, haciendo uso del express validator, validaba el contenido del objeto de esta manera:

```
check('codCiu')
    .exists()
    .isObject()

,check('codCiu.dptCiu')
    
    .isLength({max:2})
    .custom((value)=>{


        return value.indexOf(" ")
    })

,check('codCiu.ciuCiu')
   
    .isLength({max:3})
    .custom((value)=>{
        return value.indexOf(" ")
    })
```

Deseo hacer lo mismo pero ahora en NestJs, pero no se como hacerlo, ya que únicamente puedo validar el objeto pero no su contenido...

```
@IsObject()
codCiu:object;
```

Answer (score 0):

¿Ese objeto siempre será el mismo? Si fuese así, podrías crear una clase de ese objeto y declararlo en la clase que mencionas

```
class ObjetoCustom {
   @IsNumber()
   id: number;
   ... otros campos
}

codCiu: ObjetoCustom;
```

También echale un ojo a la librería class-validator